# How to pass on form data in route with other variables?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this form

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 offset-2">
                <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-label-group mt-1">
                    <label class="text-dark-orange" for="name">Naam</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control sentje-inputfield-payment" placeholder="Vul hier uw naam in" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-label-group mt-1">
                    <label class="text-dark-orange" for="note">Notitie</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="note" name="note" class="form-control sentje-inputfield-payment" placeholder="Vul hier eventueel een notitie in"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-lg-8 offset-2">
                <a href="{{ route('paymentrequest.preparePayment', [$paymentrequest->unique_link, $paymentrequest]) }}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg sentje-button">Betalen</button></a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I click the button it sends the `$paymentrequest` with it. (I already sent that parameter to the view) How would I also pass on the data that has been putted in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give your form an ID and make the action that of the `<a>` URL:

   ```
   <form action="{{ route('paymentrequest.preparePayment', [$paymentrequest->unique_link, $paymentrequest]) }}" id="my-form" class="form-signin" method="POST">
   ```
2. Change your `<a>` to just `button` with the `type="submit"` and a `form="<form-id>"`

   ```
   <button type="submit" form="my-form" class="btn btn-block btn-lg sentje-button">Betalen</button>
   ```

Using the form property allows you to close your form tag and keep the button outside and allows you to still submit it and keep your code neater.